# css code in /stylesheets/products.css.scss not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a product scaffold and I have put some custom css code in /stylesheets/products.css.scss file, now when I run the server and see the rendered html file (/products/index.html.erb), **I am not seeing that css being rendered**

What am I doing wrong ? application.css has

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Comment: How are you including this on your HTML? What ".css" files you see in your development rendered HTML?

Comment: @Leito - I am including it like this -  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

Comment: What about the second question?

Comment: @Leito -  sorry missed that, I am only seeing "bootstrap_and_overrides.css", since all the other files are scss, though there are 10+ scss files and I was hoping that they will get converted into css and will be shown in the html code!

Comment: You have `gem 'sass-rails'` in your Gemfile?

Comment: @Leito - yes, I have   "gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'" in gemfile

Comment: `/stylesheets/products.css.scss` ? this is the project root or what?

Comment: @phoet - no, it is a simple rails app with scaffold as Product which created scss file in /stylesheets and .js.coffee file in /javascript folders of asset folder

Comment: as far as i can see, this should work! what exactly is in that file and what do you expect so see on what part of the page?